# Why My Apex Trigger doesn't support Bulk Upload (Batch>1)

Tags: apex, bulk, bulkification

May be somebody can explain me.
**Story:** I have a Separate Custom Object for SIC codes (SIC_Lookup__c). It is linked to Account Object with a [Account].SIC_LkUp__c Look Up field.

---

**I want:** When standard `[Account].Sic` field is populated/changed to transfer this change to the Look Up Sic field `[Account].SIC_LkUp__c.` 
In other words system should check the value of `[Account].Sic`, find the corresponding System `[SIC_Lookup__c].Id` Value and copy to the `[Account].SIC_LkUp__c.`

---

The script bellow works but only for Batch=1, not for bulk Upload. Why? Is it possible to fix?
After Update I would like to avoid unless it will not require extra copy procedure to another Object fields. By default After Update doesn't allow copy values on the object itself (read only exception)

---

My second question is does anybody knows how is it better to avoid nullpointer exception here: `if(SIC_LkUp_Map.get(a.Sic).ID != Null)` - it seems that the statement triggers it itself instead of just checking.

---

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

```
//_____________________________________________________________________________________________
trigger Account_BI_BU on Account (before insert, before update) {
    set<String> cSic = new set<String>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.New){
        if(!String.isBlank(a.Sic)){
//SIC Clean-up. It Removes 0's in the beginning, Removes White Spaces. It also converts to the standard format (adding 0 in beggining to 1 and 3 digits SICs).
            String SicCor = a.Sic.deleteWhitespace();
            if(Pattern.matches('\\d+?',SicCor)){
                SicCor = string.valueOf(integer.valueOf(SicCor));
                if(Pattern.matches('\\d{1}|\\d{3}',SicCor)){
                    SicCor = '0'+SicCor;
                }
            a.Sic = SicCor;
//Add Standard Sic to a set of variables if it's not Null
            cSic.add(SicCor);
            }
        }}
//If the Set contains the Sic, match the Sic to SIC_Lookup__c.ExternalID__c and ID of the SIC_Lookup__c record
    if(!cSic.isEmpty()){
        Map<String,SIC_Lookup__c> SIC_LkUp_Map = new Map<String,SIC_Lookup__c>();
    for (SIC_Lookup__c sl : [select Id, ExternalID__c from SIC_Lookup__c where ExternalID__c IN: cSic]) {
    SIC_LkUp_Map.put(sl.ExternalID__c, sl);
        }

            for (Account a : Trigger.New){
           //If Account.Sic field has been Changed or the new record has been created, run trigger.new
         if(trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && a.Sic != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).Sic)){
                            try{if(SIC_LkUp_Map.get(a.Sic).ID != Null){
//Update of the LookUp field with before insert/update method creates recursive run issue. It can be hadled by the class below
              if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){
                a.SIC_LkUp__c = SIC_LkUp_Map.get(a.Sic).Id;
                    }
                  }} catch(NullPointerException n) {
              a.SIC_LkUp__c = Null;
                }
            }



}}


}


//********************************************

    public Class checkRecursive{
    private static boolean run = true;
    public static boolean runOnce(){
    if(run){
     run=false;
     return true;
    }else{
        return run;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add any error detail you have to your post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is causing problem

```
if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){
   a.SIC_LkUp__c = SIC_LkUp_Map.get(a.Sic).Id;
   }
```

I can not understand any use case of controlling recursion by your question. But this is not a right place to control recursion. It should be at trigger level and not a inside code statement. Your code will start working once you remove this recursion check code or may be move recursion check to trigger level.

For your second question it should be done by below way:

```
if(SIC_LkUp_Map.get(a.Sic) != Null)
```

If map returns null as record, null.id will cause you null pointer exception.